# deserializing JSON object with nested fields, results

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I want to deserialize a JSON object using C#.
The data I get is somewhat nested in a few fields, see "grade" as example

```
...,"name":"John Doe","grade":{"title":"exampleTitle"}, "sthelse":[null],...
```

When I deserialize this, what will be in the grade field of the resulting object?

I would assume

```
Console.WriteLine(grade);
```

would result in

> title:exampleTitle

but I'm unsure.

Comment: Well what are you trying to deserialize it *as*? Do you have a class model, or are you just trying to deserialize to a `JObject` or similar?

Comment: So what a problem here? You could use JObject and get the nested fields...

Comment: @JonSkeet class model, I (for now) declared grade to be a string.

Comment: Well don't, because it's not a string - it's an object with a `title` field. So declare a `Grade` class with a property called `Title` of type `string`, and then make your `Grade` property a property of that type...

Comment: @JonSkeet now there is that nesting part I expected. Thanks!